# Docker container memory upper limit

Tags: linux, docker, memory, containers, limit

I'm trying to find an answer to a question what is the maximum possible amount of memory assigned to a Docker container on Intel Linux 64 bit OS?

Comment: no limit unless you add `--memory` parameter to the container

Comment: @LinPy are you saying I can assign 128TB of RAM to a single Docker container on Linux x86_64?

Comment: I mean it can use what the os and the host can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref. the [user memory constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-memory-constraints):

> Examples:
>
> `$ docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`
>
> We set nothing about memory, this means the processes in the container can use as much memory and swap memory as they need.

Unless you explicitly limit the memory (`--memory`) then your limit will be the amount of memory assigned to the host. `docker stats <container>` displays the memory limits (among other stats):

[image]